# dropzone JS Preview element option

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I have two dropzones

**JS Code to initialize**

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(".js-dropzone").dropzone({
  url: 'upload_files.php',
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  previewTemplate: $('.form_dropzone_preview').html()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- first -->

<div class="form_dropzone js-dropzone></div>
    <div class=" dropzone-previews js-previews-1 "></div>

    <!-- second -->
    <div class="form_dropzone js-dropzone></div>
<div class="dropzone-previews js-previews-2"></div>
```

How I can set `previewsContainer` `.js-previews-1` for first dropzone and `.js-previews-2` for second ?

Comment: You can't ... you need two selectors

Comment: The [docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options) say `Can be a plain HTMLElement or a CSS selector` therefore you'll need to define each dropzone individually, instead of applying the same settings to both as you currently are.

Comment: Yes exactly what @RoryMcCrossan saying

Comment: checkout https://gist.github.com/bennadel/7967676

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
function initDropzone(id, previewsContainer) {
    new Dropzone(
    id, //id of drop zone element
    {
        url: 'upload_files.php',
        previewTemplate: $('.form_dropzone_preview').html(),
        previewsContainer: previewsContainer
        // other options 
     }
}

(function($) {
    "use strict";

    //  Dropzone
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    for ( var i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
        initDropzone('#dropzone_'+i,'#dropzone_previews_'+i);
    }

}(jQuery));
```

HTML

```
first
<div class="form_dropzone" id="dropzone_1"></div>
<div class="dropzone-previews" id="dropzone_previews_1"></div>

second
<div class="form_dropzone" id="dropzone_2"></div>
<div class="dropzone-previews" id="dropzone_previews_2"></div>
```